# Draw a line after the text to the end of line

Tags: html, css

I have a title for a page, I want to have a line that begins after the text and that goes to the end of the line, whatever is the width of the window, kind of :

`TITLE----------------------------------------------------------------------------`

but a full line, I just wrote it with `-`for demonstration. I saw `<hr>` but it always go the line after, it doesn't stay after the text. I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458317/force-background-to-draw-on-till-end-of-line) but that's not exactly what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: A full width, half height span with border ??

Comment: I tried but it didn't work...I tried : `<span style="border-top-style:solid` but it doesn't display anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here s another answer. You can just use a fieldset element instead

```
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Title comes here</legend>
  </fieldset>
```

and style it this

```
fieldset { border-top:1px solid #333; }
```

Here s a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SQujE/

Comment: it's almost perfect...I don't understand why...but mine is always written like that : `--TITLE-------`it's not stick to the left as your example does...is it a simple option?

Comment: yes just set padding (and margin) to 0px on the fieldset element in your CSS. If it still doesnt work then add !important to it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MFhsV/ You can get rid of margin and !important if it works without it.

Answer (score 2):

Try having two DIV elements.  The first one can be 100% page width and can have the second one in it.

Let the inner DIV contain your "Title" text and autosize itself.  Make the background of the outer div an image of a line, and make the background of the inner div the same color as the normal page background.

Comment: I like the idea! but I don't understand why, it doesn't work...I have this `<p><div class='ligne'><span class='TitleClass'>  TITLE  </span></div></p>` and in my `CSS`: `div.ligne {width:100%;background-color:#e5e5e5;} span.TitleClass {background-color=#FF0000;
}` I tried first with color to simplified...the only 'difference' it that my second tag is a `span`

Answer (score 2):

For the hr element you can use the CSS property display with the value inline-block along with a width

```
hr { display: inline-block; width: 90%; }
```

and in your HTML,

```
Title<hr />
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/67f2E/

A little variation with the word 'Title' and the hr element aligned vertically to middle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wHPQA/

Comment: that would be good but I have a lot of different title to manage that way and I want it to set is width alone. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This question may be old, but I needed this effect today and achieved it using an absolutely positioned CSS pseudo-element. First, place a wrapper around the text of your element in HTML:

```
    <h3>
        <span>Title</span>
    </h3>
```

We will use this span to cover up the part of the line (pseudo-element) that overlaps with the text. This will give the effect of a line from the end of the text to the end of the line, but in reality the line is always 100% width of the container.

```
    h3 {
      /* we will absolutely position the line relative to the parent element (h3) */
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    h3 span {
      background: #dedede;   /* make this the same color as the page background! */
      padding-right: 0.5em;  /* this will be the 'margin' from the text to the line */
    }
    /* Add Line After Text*/
    h3 span::after {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background: #919098;
      /* position the line within the parent element */
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0.5em;                           /* half the height of the text from the bottom */
      left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);  /* horizontally center it */
      z-index: -1;                             /* display it behind the parent */
    }
```

[Results of this Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O031k.png)

I did this with a heading element, but you can easily use this effect on a paragraph or other element by swapping tags around. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Title<hr style="display: inline-block; width: 90%; margin-bottom: 4px; margin-left: 5px;" />
```

Based on saganbyte's answer. `margin-bottom` play with the offset from the bottom and `margin-left` from the left. Logic isn't ?

Comment: well it is, but as I said to saganbyte, it's not enough auto. for me, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that my answer is a bit late but it was long to do what you wanted.

**HTML :** `<span id="test" >HI</span>`

**JS :**

```
document.getElementById("test").style.position="relative";
var line=document.createElement("div");
line.setAttribute("style","width:"+(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].offsetWidth-document.getElementById("test").offsetWidth-1)+"px;height:1px;position:absolute;top:6px;left:"+(document.getElementById("test").offsetWidth+1)+"px;background-color:black;");
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(line);
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/QrEgH

**Bonus :**
1-No CSS, just a small block of JS.
2-A very small HTML, you just add the span.
3-This fiddle that is less compressed and with comments : http://jsfiddle.net/VfCJ3